# Problem with balancing a rotation in an AVL tree JAVA

Tags: java

Im writing a basic AVL tree that holds Objects, im having a Stackoverflow error (lol) in my code to recurse through the tree to get the height of the current node. I dont think my height code is actually the problem so much that my rotation causes my height code to have the problem.

So what I do is I recurse through the children of the node until I reach a null node which returns 0, the next/preceding call (depending on how you look at it) returns the maximum of the return the call on that node + 1 vs whatever the call on the other child ends up being. It should be pretty clear how it works when you see it.

the rotation creates a temporary node from the appropriate child and alters the node and sets it to the child of the temporary node and sets the parent values to the proper nodes. (Each node has a reference not only to a left and right node but the parent node)

The insertion method works fine as far as I can tell, I do have a problem with an infinite loop in my delete method but thats another question for another time.

Hopefully I have given enough info, let me know if there is anything I can clarify this is my first post here. but any help is appreciated, this one even has my instructor stumped.

Thanks for even taking the time to read this wall of text.

```
import java.lang.Math;
/**
This is an AVL binary search tree class it uses a AVLNode to create an AVL Binary search tree.
 */


public class AVLTree {
        AVLNode root;
        Index empty;

        public AVLTree(){
            root = null;
        }

        public void insert(Object o, String ssNumber){
            if (root == null){
                root = new AVLNode(o);
                System.out.print("adding root");
            }
            else{
            AVLNode current = root;
            AVLNode node = new AVLNode(o);
            while (current != null){
                    if (((Comparable)current.getData()).compareTo(ssNumber) < 0){
                        if (current.getRight() != null){
                            current = current.getRight();
                        }
                        else{
                        //  System.out.println(((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial() +  " CURRENT DATA");
                            current.setRight(node);
                            current.getRight().setParent(current);
                        //  System.out.println("adding " + ((Index)o).getSocial() + "to the right of" + ((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial());
                            balanceTree(current);
                        //  if (current.getParent() != null)
                        //      System.out.println("the right child of " + (((Index)(current.getParent().getData())).getSocial()) + " is now " + (((Index)((current.getRight()).getData())).getSocial()) );
                            current=null;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (((Comparable)current.getData()).compareTo(ssNumber) > 0) {
                        if (current.getLeft()!= null){
                            current = current.getLeft();
                        }
                        else{
                        //  System.out.println(((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial() +  " CURRENT DATA");
                            current.setLeft(node);
                            current.getLeft().setParent(current);
                        //  System.out.println("adding " + ((Index)o).getSocial() + "to the left of" + ((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial());
                            balanceTree(current);
                        //  if (current.getParent() != null)
                        //      System.out.println("the left child of " + (((Index)(current.getParent().getData())).getSocial()) + " is now " + (((Index)((current.getLeft()).getData())).getSocial()) );
                            current=null;
                        }
                    }
            }
            }

        }
        public boolean delete(String ssNumber){
            AVLNode current = root;
            AVLNode parent = null;
            while (current.getData() != null){
                if (((Comparable)current.getData()).compareTo(ssNumber) > 0){
                    if(current.getLeft() != null){
                        parent = current;
                        current = current.getLeft();

                    }
                    else{
                        //System.out.print(((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial() + "not found");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (((Comparable)current.getData()).compareTo(ssNumber) < 0){
                    if (current.getRight()!=null){
                        parent = current;
                        current = current.getRight();
                    }
                    else{
                        //System.out.print(((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial() + "not found");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (current.getLeft() != null && current.getRight() != null){
                        AVLNode leftHighest = null;
                        AVLNode temp = current.getLeft();
                            while (temp.getRight() != null){
                                temp = temp.getRight();
                            }
                            leftHighest.setData(temp.getData());
                            temp.setData(current.getData());
                            current.setData(leftHighest.getData());
                            return delete(ssNumber);

                    }
                    if (current.getLeft() == null && current.getRight() != null){
                        if (parent == null){
                            root = current.getRight();
                        }
                        if (current == parent.getLeft()){
                            parent.setLeft(current.getRight());
                        }
                        else{
                            parent.setRight(current.getRight());
                        }
                    }
                    else if (current.getRight() == null && current.getLeft() != null){
                        if (parent == null){
                            root = current.getLeft();
                        }
                        if (current == parent.getLeft()){
                            parent.setLeft(current.getLeft());
                        }
                        else{
                            parent.setRight(current.getLeft());
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        current.setData(null);
                        return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
        //System.out.print(((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial() + "not found");
        return false;
            }

        public int find(String ssNumber){
            AVLNode current = root;
            while (current.getData() != null){
                if (((Comparable)current.getData()).compareTo(ssNumber) > 0){
                    if(current.getLeft() != null){
                        current = current.getLeft();
                    }
                    else{
                        //System.out.print(((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial() + "not found");
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                else if (((Comparable)current.getData()).compareTo(ssNumber) < 0){
                    if (current.getRight()!=null){
                        current = current.getRight();
                    }
                    else{
                        //System.out.print(((Index)(current.getData())).getSocial() + "not found");
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    return ((Index)(current.getData())).getArrayIndex();

                    }

            }
            return -1;
        }
        public void clear(){
            root = null;
        }

        //gets the height of the node's subtrees. Uses recursion to find the max height returns the highest value of each traversal adding 1 for each step.
        private int getHeight(AVLNode node){
            if (node == null){
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
             //int x = getHeight( node.getLeft() );
             //int y = getHeight( node.getRight() );
             //return Math.max( x, y ) + 1;
          return Math.max(getHeight(node.getLeft()), getHeight(node.getRight())) + 1;
        }
        }
        //uses the value of getBalance to decide which type of rotation to undergo, and rotates the node by creating a temporary node from the proper child based on the type value.
        //the type value will be passed the balance.
        private AVLNode rotateNodes(AVLNode node, int type){
            AVLNode temp;
            //System.out.println("step C");
            if (type == -2){
                temp = node.getRight();
                temp.setParent(node.getParent());
                if (node.getParent() != null){
                    if (node == node.getParent().getLeft()){
                        temp.getParent().setLeft(temp);
                    }
                    else{
                        temp.getParent().setRight(temp);
                    }
                }
                node.setRight(temp.getLeft());
                if (node.getRight() != null){
                    node.getRight().setParent(node);
                }
                temp.setLeft(node);
                return temp;
            }
            else if (type == 2){
                temp = node.getLeft();
                temp.setParent(node.getParent());
                if (node.getParent() != null){
                    if (node == node.getParent().getLeft()){
                        temp.getParent().setLeft(temp);
                    }
                    else{
                        temp.getParent().setRight(temp);
                    }
                }
                node.setLeft(temp.getRight());
                if (node.getLeft() != null){
                    node.getLeft().setParent(node);
                }
                temp.setRight(node);
                node.setParent(temp);
                return temp;
            }
            else
                return node;
        }
        // Runs the methods necessary to balance a tree on each node until it reaches the root.
        private void balanceTree(AVLNode node){
            AVLNode temp;
            while (node != null){
                int balance = getHeight(node.getLeft()) - getHeight(node.getRight());
                if (balance == 2 || balance == -2){
                //System.out.println("step a");
                temp = rotateNodes(node, balance);
                //System.out.println("rotated");
                node.setData(temp.getData());
                node.setLeft(temp.getLeft());
                node.setRight(temp.getRight());
                node.setParent(temp.getParent());
                }
                else {
                //System.out.println("moving on");
                node = node.getParent();
                }
            }

        }
        //check balance
    }



    /**
This is an AVL node in a AVL binary tree it contains data and references to its two possible children and it's parent.
 */


public class AVLNode {
    private Object data;
    private AVLNode left;
    private AVLNode right;
    private AVLNode parent;

    public AVLNode(Object o){
        data = o;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        parent = null;
    }
    public AVLNode(){
        data = null;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        parent = null;
    }
    public Object getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public AVLNode getLeft(){
        return left;
    }
    public AVLNode getRight(){
        return right;
    }
    public void setData(Object index){
        data = index;
    }
    public void setLeft(AVLNode node){
        left = node;
    }
    public void setRight(AVLNode node){
        right = node;
    }
    public void setParent(AVLNode node){
        parent = node;
    }
    public AVLNode getParent(){
        return parent;
    }
}

    /**

The is a person class it holds 6 data fields about a person
 */


public class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String socialSec;
    private String phoneNum;
    private char gender;
    private String date;

    public Person(String lastName, String firstName, String socialSec, String phoneNum, char gender, String date) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.socialSec = socialSec;
    this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.date = date;
    }

    public String getLast(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public String getFirst(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getSocial(){
        return socialSec;
    }
    public void setSocial(String string){
        this.socialSec = string;
    }
    public String getPhone(){
        return phoneNum;
    }
    public char getGender(){
        return gender;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return ("Lastname: " + lastName + "\nFirstname: " + firstName + "\nSocial Security " + socialSec +
            "\nPhone Number: " + phoneNum + "\ngender " + gender);
    }
}

    /**
This is an index object it will contain the data type used as reference the binary tree, the social, and the references location in the array
 */


public class Index implements Comparable {
    String social;
    int arrayIndex;

    public Index(String social, int arrayIndex) {
        this.social = social;
        this.arrayIndex = arrayIndex;

    }
    public String getSocial(){
        return social;
    }
    public void setSocial(String social){
        this.social = social;
    }
    public int getArrayIndex(){
        return arrayIndex;
    }
    public void setArrayIndex(int arrayIndex){
        this.arrayIndex = arrayIndex;
    }
    public int compareTo(Object o){
        return social.compareTo((String)o);
    }

}
Here is the data read in from datafile (this is fake info)

    Hattell Zara    568472178   9562266952  F   8/23/1985
    Poff    Naomi   070028388   1868991633  F   10/25/1967
    Jackson Finley  766879776   6317272316  M   8/28/1984
    Lark    Kasey   278473635   4953108522  F   9/19/1967
    Grifith Josh    223948515   5916186412  M   11/21/1964
    Grimsby Mitchel 057848901   4921537476  M   10/28/1969
    Heesicker   Samara  578308596   0089823308  F   7/27/1964
    Amos    Kasey   148842321   7949241129  F   2/10/1985
    Johnson Angeline    003513447   8828061677  F   4/21/1977
    Aldridge    John    418953690   5006720120  M   6/23/1968
    Mckibbon    Vasilios    523212165   0040010068  M   7/30/1972
    Woodhouse   Jacob   522626205   6985940430  M   7/31/1966
    Newell  Shante  022753752   8483983762  F   2/24/1978
    Ramer   Tyler   025694346   6123635287  M   9/14/1980
    Leatherman  Tige    297071697   1106435680  M   8/11/1981
    Johnston    Halle   263543220   3417907710  F   11/17/1960
    Aber    Myah    669617355   3276358736  F   12/10/1961
    Frizzle Archie  150388947   1472418810  M   8/5/1960
    Mcdivit Ashley  294735567   2017661755  M   11/3/1978
    Jackson Sophie  698928462   0185800213  F   3/18/1960
    Bechtel William 700321659   1376473348  M   11/30/1974
    Larimer Alessi  745219302   2445633750  F   12/12/1964
    Bodler  Amelie  424759320   2676866912  F   11/25/1961
    Niswander   Ebony   218384979   7468337166  F   12/3/1970
    Overlees    Minnesha    594664590   9411189605  F   8/5/1981
    Jones   Haley   692179128   9046757546  F   3/24/1968
    Weiner  Lee 111223333   2223334444  M   2/31/1978


    /*
    main class to create a Binary search tree
    */

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.regex.*;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class AVLdatabase {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        AVLTree anAVLTree = new AVLTree();
        File file = new File("datafile.txt");
        List<Person> dataArray = new ArrayList<Person>();
            try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            //read lines and place the data into person objects
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\t");
                while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                    Person record = new Person(lineScanner.next(),lineScanner.next(),lineScanner.next(),lineScanner.next(),(lineScanner.next()).charAt(0),lineScanner.next());
                    System.out.print(record.getLast() + " ");
                    System.out.print(record.getFirst() + " ");
                    System.out.print(record.getSocial() + " ");
                    System.out.println();
                    Index index = new Index(record.getSocial(), dataArray.size());
                    dataArray.add(record);
                    anAVLTree.insert(index, record.getSocial());
                    System.out.println("The array index is " + (dataArray.size()-1));
                }
            }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.print("No File");
                }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Gisted: https://gist.github.com/988340255959eb1de8ba

Answer (score 1):

Your height code looks fine.  I would assume that your rotation code is causing one of your leaves to link back to an inner node.

E.g.:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
```

May be becoming:

```
   B
  / \
 C   A
    / \
   B   C
```

with A still having a reference to B, which has a reference to A which has a reference to B, which has a reference to A, etc.  The A -> B would, of course, be referencing the root B, but I can't picture that here.

Answer (score 0):

You are the best person at debugging your own code, but I can provide some general suggestions:

1. Not sure if you're aware of this, but in the following code:

   ```
   temp = node.getRight();
   temp.setParent(node.getParent());
   ```

   Correct me if I'm wrong, but `temp` is copied by reference, not by value.  After these operations, `node.getRight().getParent()` will equal `temp.getParent()`.  That's probably not the issue, but you should be aware of it.
2. Watch out for side effects.  Whatever you did in the previous line affects the following lines.
3. Ditch the `AVLNode parent;` , as maintaining it introduces cruft.  Bear in mind that you will probably need to make a recursive subroutine for `delete()` to keep track of the parent.  Alternatively, make your accessor methods for AVLNode automatically maintain parent links.